# Facebook Graph API returns empty object for /{user-id}/feed but works for /me/feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

folks,

I've been struggling with this for some time, and I just can't seem to find a solution.

When I hit /me/feed using my FB app's credentials, I return everything just fine.

But when I try to hit /{my-user-id}/feed, I get an empty object.

FB says that /me/ is just a shortcut to the /{user-id}/ node, so it *should* work just the same. But it doesn't.

I thought it must have been an app permissions issue, but if this were the case, I would think that even /me/ would return empty.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of access token are you using for the request with the user id?

Comment: I've been using a User Access Token generated by the Graph API Explorer with user_friends, user_posts, user_status permissions.

Comment: And the access token is for that user who’s id you are using? If so, that seems to be a bug, suggest you file a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Correct, the access token is for me (I've just been using my own FB profile for testing). Hmmm, I guess I just assumed it was on my end, but yes, I suppose it could very well just be a bug!

Comment: Are you using an app scoped user ID? if not, it won't work.

Comment: Ahhh, yep. That's what was doing it. I was using the Facebook user ID, not the app-scoped user ID. Thanks much, @javier-de-la-cueva! And thanks for your help, too, @CBroe.